# Compare fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack

I've got the next code to switch between 4 fragments in a container [Main, A, B, C].

I need back button to go back to **[Main]** no matter how the user has navigated through fragments. For example, if I go **[Main] >> [A] >> [C]** when pressing back should go to **[Main]**.

But I'm not getting the desired result. I think that I'm not doing well the coparisson between fragments.

```
Launcher MainFragment = new Launcher();

public void switchFragment(Fragment pFragment) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment currentFragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

    if (pFragment == MainFragment){
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.fragment_container, pFragment).commit();
    }
    else if (currentFragment == MainFragment && pFragment != MainFragment){
        //Fragment fr = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, pFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
    else {
        //Fragment fr = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, pFragment).commit();
    }
    currentFragment = pFragment;
}
```

**UPDATE--**

I've seen this way is working better, but still makes issue. If I navigate through some fragments without returning back to the Main fragment, when I press back it doesn't go back. It's like if there was some issue with the popbackstack().

```
public void switchFragment(Fragment pFragment) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment currentFragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

    if (pFragment.equals(MainFragment)){
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.fragment_container, pFragment).commit();
    }
    else if (currentFragment.equals(MainFragment) && !pFragment.equals(MainFragment)){
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, pFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
    else {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, pFragment).commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try and check by using `instanceOf` in place of `==` and `!=` in `switchFragment`

Comment: Tells me `incompatible conditional operand types`

Comment: is overriding the return-button an alternative for you?

Comment: @bofredo I don't have return-button. I'm developing for a board where the app suposes to be an interfaze over android stock. So the only way to go back is with my custom back key

Answer (score 0):

This functionality can be achieved by removing .addToBackStack from your fragment transactions.

Here is the Android reference for back stack functionality within fragments: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html#back-fragments

Comment: Yes, I've only set the .addToBackStack to save the MainFragment to the backstack on the else if condition. This condition sees if the current fragment is the main, so in this case it saves to the backstack

Comment: Are you modifying the onBackPressed method at all?

Answer (score 0):

I finally get the dessired result just replacing the fragment I want on the back_key onClickListener:

```
final OnClickListener goBack = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragment_container, MainFragment).commit();
    }
};
```

This way, if In the future I need to go back to another fragment instead of the Main, I'll just add a condition to compare fragment tags and do something depending the tag.